# subprocess powershell execution not running after creating exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I'm having an issue with my code after creating an .exe file with pyinstaller.
I use `Popen()` to execute a powershell script, but it seems like it's not executing the script in the .exe version while in the .py it does work.

I checked other answers on stackoverflow, where it stated that yo need to redirect everything, but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure how I can further debug or what the source of the issue is.

```
command = f'powershell.exe; Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass; {path}\config\ps_presto_cli.ps1 -path {path} -usr_pass {usr_pass} -usr_name {usr_name} -sql_code {sql_code} -file_name {file_name}.csv -schema {schema}'

process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr, stdin = process.communicate()
```

the command that I use to create the .exe file:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --noconsole --onefile file.py
```

Does anybody know why in the .exe version `Popen()` doesn't work in the above example? Or how I can further debug it (the .exe is not throwing an error).

**Edit:**
I also tried:

```
Popen(['powershell','-command', 'Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass', command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

command= f'{path}\config\ps_presto_cli.ps1 -path {path} -usr_pass {usr_pass} -usr_name {usr_name} -sql_code {sql_code} -file_name {file_name}.csv -schema {schema}'
```

but that didn't work either. Moving the `'Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass'` to the ps1 file doesn't work either. the code just hangs when I do that.

**Edit2:**
this topic was marked duplicate, but the referred post doesn't have anything in common with the issue experienced here.

Comment: As an aside, this code has injection issues. A `usr_pass` value containing `; ...some command here...; ` can cause a bad day.

Comment: Bigger concern, though, is that `powershell.exe; some powershell command here` is waiting for `powershell.exe` to exit before it runs `some powershell command here`; that's not the same as making `some powershell command here` be the input to `powershell.exe`.

Comment: ...which is to say, this isn't just a pyinstaller problem; this code shouldn't _ever_ work, even without pyinstaller.

Comment: Not sure how to respond to that given that the code does work. Please note that the powershell.exe command is sent towards cmd to open powershell.How would it need to be rewritten as i don't understand what the issue is

Comment: The linked duplicate describes how to rewrite it. Pass the command to run in powershell _as an argument to_ powershell, not a subsequent command.

Comment: Also see https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/executing-powershell-from-python/ -- the approach it suggests (`subprocess.Popen(['powershell', '-Cmd', string_with_your_powershell_command_here], capture_output=True)`) is exactly what I'd idiomatically expect as someone coming in with Python and UNIX shell expertise.

Comment: I tried the approach you suggest, but it doesn't run the code, it just hangs.
`capture_output` wasn't accepted as an input to `Popen()`

`'-Cmd'` should probably be `'-Command'`?

Also I don't understand what I should do with the command `'Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass'`. If I don't set it, I can't run the code, but if I add it like this, it errors out:

`Popen(['powershell','-command', 'Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass', command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: I also tried adding it to the ps1 file but then it also doesn't work.

Comment: You've convinced me that the question is distinct from the ones already on the site; it's now reopened. I may come back and add my answer after I have a personal Windows VM handy to test it on.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question thanks to @CharlesDuffy:

```
command= f'Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass; {path}\config\ps_presto_cli.ps1 -path {path} -usr_pass {usr_pass} -usr_name {usr_name} -sql_code {sql_code} -file_name {file_name}.csv -schema {schema}'


CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000

process = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

Now the executable does work, the only visual issue that remained was that when it executes the ps1 file, it pops up a terminal to execute.

`creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag helped with that, though I had to set the variable for `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` for it to work

Comment: Just for somebody else who's dealing with this, creationflags is only for Window$.